# SQL join when there is a corresponding post or not

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join a table that may or may not have a relevant post and want to see even those ones where there isn't. Short example:

Select * from customer cu
join customerphone cp on cu.customer_id = cp.customer_id

This far no problems because I only want customers who have a phone number registered but how do I join an another table where not all the customers have a row and I want in end result also those without a row to be shown. Is this even possible to do or should I then afterwards just check whether there is relevant data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a left (outer) join. Example:

```
select c.CustomerId, p.PhoneNumber, cc.Complaint
from Customer c
inner join CustomerPhone p on p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
left join CustomerComplaint cc on cc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

The data that you get where there is no matching record will be null, i.e. where there is no complaint, cc.Complaint will return null.

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
Select * from customer cu left outer join customerphone cp on cu.customer_id = cp.customer_id
```

This will result in a NULL being shown when there is not a corresponding record.

If you want to provide a default value you can use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) in TSQL or [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an OUTER JOIN.

This is a good link:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ANSIISOSQLSupport.php#outer_join

Hope that helps,

-Mark